Error when building for iOS with Expo EAS "Provided Distribution Certificate is no longer valid on Apple's server"
I'm trying to build my Expo app. I already built it for Android, but now I'm struggling to create a release on iOS to upload on TestFlight.
I have the apple developer account of my university, and they added our bundle ID there(I'm not an admin).
When I try to build with EAS, it requires a p12 file.
So, I tried to generate it in this way:

From Keychain Access I created a CSR(by adding my mail and name) and then on Apple Developers I uploaded it(Certificates > +), so I downloaded a .cer file

I opened the .cer on Keychain Access and I dragged it under "login" section

From there I've exported the p12 file


But that p12 gives me always this error when I run npx eas build --platform ios  :

Provided Distribution Certificate is no longer valid on Apple's server

after submitting the p12 file.
Can someone help us? Thanks in advance for your availability :)
